# Set a hardcoded day and month for a given year in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I am working on a small query and would like a little assistance formatting a date

**Situation**

I am accepting a payment date and based on that date I set the expiration date to 31st March of either this year or the next. So if the payment is made in January, the exp date is 31st March of the current year, if it's made in August, it's the 31st March of the next year. 
This is my query.

```
BEGIN
IF DATEPART(MONTH,@paydate) BETWEEN 1 and 3 
UPDATE usrBio
SET ExpDate=DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())+'-31'+'-03'
WHERE IDnum =@IDnum
ELSE IF
DATEPART(MONTH,@paydate) BETWEEN 4 and 12
UPDATE usrBio
SET ExpDate=DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()+1)+'-31'+'-03'
WHERE IDnum =@IDnum
END
```

The problem I am having is that I am unsure of how to set the month and day as instead of being concatenating to the year string, it's subtracting from the year date and my result is `1905-06-07 00:00:00.000` where I'm expecting `2017-31-03`.

Comment: `DATEPART` isnt `mySQL` do you mean `SQL Server`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza changed the tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you trying year as number instead of string

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/MJJDG80621)**

```
SELECT CAST( DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()+1) 
             AS varchar(5)) +'-03'+'-31'
```

And you can optimize your logic like this

```
UPDATE usrBio
SET ExpDate = CAST( CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,@paydate) BETWEEN 1 and 3 
                         THEN DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE())
                         WHEN DATEPART(MONTH,@paydate) BETWEEN 4 and 12 
                         THEN DATEPART(YEAR,GETDATE()+1) 
                    END AS varchar(4)
                  ) +'-03'+'-31'
```

Comment: my ExpDate is a datefield, I believe I will get an error assigning a varchar?do i convert it back to a date time?

Comment: As a query / stored proc it executes and runs fine, but running it as a store proc produces that error, i even tried casting back the results to a datetime

Comment: Doesn't make sense. Can you show me the code?, Have you tried Jhon solution?

Comment: Could have something to do with the collation on the server. It is generally best to use a form of the date that any collation will recognize such as YYYYMMDD

Comment: @HLGEM Is probably right try use `+'-03'+'-31'` Both my demo and Jhon use that notation.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yea i realized that as soon as he said that.

Answer (score 3):

If 2012+, consider **DateFromParts()**

**Example 1**

```
Declare @PayDate date = '2017-08-31'

Select DateFromParts(Year(@PayDate)+IIF(Month(@PayDate)>3,1,0),3,31)
```

**Returns**

```
2018-03-31
```

### ----------------------

**Example 2**

```
Declare @PayDate date = '2017-03-31'

Select DateFromParts(Year(@PayDate)+IIF(Month(@PayDate)>3,1,0),3,31)
```

**Returns**

```
2017-03-31
```

**

> **Edit - For 2008**

**

```
Select DateAdd(YEAR,case when Month(@PayDate)>3 then 1 else 0 end,str(Year(@PayDate),4)+'-03-31')
```

Comment: Helpful, thou still on 2008

Comment: @Niana See Edit - For 2008